# Asynchronously Update Page Content after Flask-Dropzone Upload

Tags: python, flask, dropzone.js

I have a simple one-page Flask app that has a Dropzone.js drop zone at the top of the page (through Flask-Dropzone) and renders previews of all previously uploaded files in a table underneath. As of now, the user must reload the page after an upload in order for the table underneath to update. I know I can set the page to reload after upload automatically and re-render the template, but I was hoping to asynchronously update the table after each file is processed (for example, if the user uploads 5 files at once and they are being processed in parallel, it would kinda suck if the page reloaded on them 5 times).

Here is my barebones code.

**app.py**

```
# app.py
app = Flask(__name__, template_folder = "./templates", static_folder="/")

"""
Uploader
"""
# dropzone for uploader
dropzone = Dropzone(app)
app.config["DROPZONE_MAX_FILE_SIZE"] = 1000 # max file size for now is 1 gb
app.config['DROPZONE_ALLOWED_FILE_TYPE'] = 'image/*' # only images

@app.route("/", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def home():
    # get all of users files
    files = get_files()

    return render_template("index.html", files = files)

@app.route("/update_table", methods=["GET"])
def update_table():
    # IDEALLY this would return either the updated table or the updated entry

@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #save file locally 
    return render_template("index.html")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=8008, debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<head>
  {{ dropzone.load_css() }}
  {{ dropzone.style('border: 2px solid blue; background-color: blue; margin: 0') }}
</head>
<body>
  {{ dropzone.create(action='upload') }}

  <table id="user_files">
    <!-- THIS TABLE SHOULD UPDATE ON EACH DROPZONE UPLOAD -->
    {% for file in files %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{file[0]}}</td>
      <td>{{file[1]}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>

  {{ dropzone.load_js() }}
  {{ dropzone.config() }}
</body>
```

I figure the solution is some sort of Ajax modification to the Flask-Dropzone config, I'm just new to Ajax so apologies for not offering more in advance.

Answer (score -1):

You can use websockets with Flask:
https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

After a file was uploaded, you can use emit()/send() the update the webpage from the python side.

You will need some javascript code to append a new <td> to the "user_files" table.
Perhaps this example can do the trick:
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp